# Path is not rooted but the directory exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to save a file on the server and I keep getting:

> The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path
>   '~\ImportFolder\chrome.dll' is not rooted.

However I created the folder in Visual Studio and it exist on the disk.
What makes a path rooted?

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
string path = Constants.importFolder;           
path = Path.Combine(path, file.FileName);
Server.MapPath(path);
file.SaveAs(path);
```

Comment: What `SaveAs` method? (Which type?)

Comment: @Richard I posted my code

Comment: You need `path = Server.MapPath(path)` - MapPath is a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It .NET strings are immutable - once created they cannot be changed, so all methods that operates on strings return a new string.

In call:

```
Server.MapPath(path);
```

you are passing `path` to `MapPath` but you are ignoring return value of that method. Change the call to store result value in the same variable:

```
path = Server.MapPath(path);
```